# Angular navigate when router parameter comes before router path

Tags: angular

In Angular, if we have the path like this: `:id/myPath` instead of `myPath/:id`, how can I use the `navigate` method properly?

I need to change the parameter when I'm in current router.

I whish to do something like this:

`this.router.navigate([this.router.currentUrl, 1]);`

but the id `1` will be placed after the url and not before, what is correct.

How to make it to render before the url? O I need to manually work with strings?

Comment: use `navigateByUrl` method in the `ActivatedRoute` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it

```
this.router.navigate([1, this.router.currentUrl]);
```